# Questions about DFA with Sigma* exiting arrow and RE

Tags: computer-science, automata

Assume Sigma* contains all english alphabet chars. Then in my DFA, I have an exiting arrow of Sigma* and another exiting arrow of "a"(symbol from the alphabet) from one state. Will this be a valid DFA? Since the execution can go two way when seeing an input of "a".. I am not sure. 
In Regular Expressions, without writing out all 48 english alphabet chars, is it possible to exclude just some chars from Sigma*? I tried to google this but it just come up with coding stuffs.
 Thank you!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want the automaton to do one thing when the input is $a$ and something else when the input is any other character?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes! I am searching for a particular string from the input.

Comment: Okay; see if my answer looks like something that you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the alphabet is $\Sigma$, then $\Sigma\setminus\{a\}$ is the set of all letters in the alphabet **except** $a$. This would be a reasonable label for the non-$a$ arrow. If you wanted to exclude both $a$ and $b$, say, you could similarly write $\Sigma\setminus\{a,b\}$. In general $A\setminus B$ is the set of things that are in $A$ but not $B$.

Comment: Oh ok! My professor only taught us * U |. Do you know if the \ symbol is valid in JFLAP? and does it need to be inside {}?

Comment: @Dino55: What I wrote is purely set-theoretic, not (so far as I know) part of any variant of a regular expression language. I’ve never worked with JFLAP, but from the quick look that I just took, I very much doubt that it recognizes this notation.

Comment: Darn it.. I really don't want to write out all 48 char on every transitions..

Comment: @Dino55: I don’t blame you!

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) I will try google once again..

Comment: @Dino55: You’re welcome; sorry that I couldn’t be of more use.